# How can I identifiy an Interruption of a Amazon EC2 Spot Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I run a single VM on Amazon's [spot market](https://aws.amazon.com/de/ec2/spot/). There, it can be interrupted at any time. How can I see if my instance was interrupted?

My instance uses a "Stop" interruption behaviour and it is part of a persistent request - hence, I guess the instance will be re-started after a certain time. The basic CloudWatch alarms do not offer the event: "VM interrupted" or "Request not fullfilled". So I do not know how long my server was down :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [Spot Instance Interruption Notices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html#spot-instance-termination-notices), which are also made available as CloudWatch events.
They allow to retrieve information about when a spot instance is stopped and should usually be triggered two minutes in advance.

Comment: the url in the documentation is old: I used curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-action instead of curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/spot/instance-action

Comment: what are the actual possibilites for what is returned by instance-action metadata?  I can't find it in their docs.